# Преобразование строки в String[]

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Есть строка `[one, two]` - преобразование `String[]` при помощи `Arrays.toString()`.
Я передаю эту строку как параметр, и мне нужно преобразовать эту строку в `String[]`. Как это сделать?

Comment: А почему вы не можете передавать сам массив вместо его строкового представления?

Comment: Элементы массива могут содержать запятые?

Comment: @I.Perevoz при чём тут дизайн вообще?

Comment: @Regent а как мне разобрать полученное в другом jsp `файле`?

Comment: @defaultlocale это строковое представление массива - тобишь массив выведен в консоль.

Comment: @Tsyklop кто-то когда-то вставляет же данные в этот JSP файл из массива. Значит, где-то этот массив есть, и его можно передать каким-то образом.

Comment: @Tsyklop в массиве может быть элемент, строковое представление которого содержит запятую? Например `new String[]{"one, lol ","two"};`

Comment: @Regent прав. Использовать промежуточную сущность как то не логично, и может привести к ошибкам. Куда правильней иметь возможность передать данный массив средствами API

Comment: @defaultlocale запятая сама по себе - это не трагедия. Проблема в запятой, за которой идёт пробел.

Comment: @Regent Как сказать. Есть случаи, когда в одном элементе запятая, а в другом пробел.

Comment: @defaultlocale а что в этом плохого? С массивом `{ "abc,", " def" }` код `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(", ")` успешно справляется.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае - никак. Если в элементе массива будет подстрока, состоящая из запятой и последующего пробела, то однозначно восстановить элементы массива не получится.

Пример такого случая:

```
String[] a = { ", ", "," };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
String[] b = { "", "", "," };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Массивы `a` и `b` содержат разные элементы, однако вывод на экран у них одинаковый:

```
[, , ,]
[, , ,]
```

Если же таких подстрок в элементах массива не будет (на что не стоит уповать на практике), то можно сделать так:

```
String[] array = { "ab,c", "d ef" };
String str = Arrays.toString(array);
String[] data = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(", ");
```

Замечание: данный код выдаст правильный результат для массива `{ "ab,c", "d ef" }`, в то время как вариант `replaceAll("\\s","").split(",")` выдаст неправильный.

---

Правильным подходом будет передавать сам массив, а не его строковое представление. Условно говоря, делать так:

```
String[] array = { "ab,c", "d ef" };
String[] data = array;
```

Comment: Из строкового представления еще необходимо будет удалить пробелы, т.к. элементы после 1-го будут его содержать перед собой.

Comment: @I.Perevoz нет, этого не нужно делать. В моём варианте `split` идёт по запятой с пробелом. Проверьте свой код на массиве `String[] array = { "ab,c", "d ef" };` - у вас будет неправильный результат.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил, однако тогда лучше использовать регулярку: ",\\s?"

Comment: @I.Perevoz нет, не лучше, ибо с ней та же проблема. Проверьте `split(",\\s?")` на всё том же моём тестовом массиве.

Comment: Согласен. "?" вообще можно убрать.

Answer (score 2):

Само собой данный вариант будет работать только при условии, что сам элемент не может содержать запятую и пробелы.

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"one","two"};
String s = Arrays.toString(arr);
arr = s.substring(1,s.length()-1).replaceAll("\\s","").split(",");
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же с учитывать только запятые и пробел после них, то должно выглядеть так:

```
arr = s.substring(1,s.length()-1).split(",\\s");
```

При этом, как уже писал в комментариях @Regent, сама концепция такого решения достаточно спорна. Куда эффективнее с точки зрения отлова будущих ошибок использовать API с соотв. методом передачи массива "как есть".